# Email sending from ASP.net fails on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I have implemented email service in my ASP.net application, and am using SmtpClient class to send email. The mail sending works perfectly fine from my local code, however it throws exception when published on the server.

The code is pretty basic, as below:

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipientEmail));
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = emailBody;

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailSettings.Username, EmailSettings.Password);
    smtp.Host = EmailSettings.Host;
    smtp.Port = EmailSettings.Port;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

The exception which is being thrown is as follows:

*"Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: "*

Comment: Is the `EmailSettings.Host` set properly? Does it point to a server that supports SSL?

Comment: I guess it should, it used to work sometimes a few days ago, but now it fails almost every time except a few occasions. Is this something that only the email service provider can confirm, or is there something that I can check in the IIS manager?

Also, when I change the email provider to Gmail, then the emails work pretty good.

Comment: Moreover, is it possible that even though the host is not set to support SSL, but the code would still send emails from localhost? This code works fine in localhost.